# non declared identifier in c++

Tags: global-variables, declaration

i am creating a global variable of a class in a header file in which all global variables are created. And the i define it in the main.
Here's the example:
in listVariables.h:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <locale>
using namespace std;

#include "dbSlice.h"
extern vector<dbSlice_str> dbSlice;//from dbSlice header i am creating the global variable
```

In main.cpp i define the variable:

```
#include "listVariables.h"
vector<dbSlice_str>                 dbSlice;
```

in dbSlice.cpp i create a global function that creates a variable and add it to the vector:

```
#include "dbSlice.h"
#include "listVariables.h"
#include "listFunctions.h"//where i declare the init_slice() function


void init_slice()
{
    dbSlice.push_back(dbSlice_str());
    dbSlice_str* slice;
    slice = new dbSlice_str();
    slice->name = "embb";
    slice->connected_users = 0;
    slice->client_weight = 100; //100% des ressources
    slice->priority = 10;
    slice->SST = 0;
    slice->preemt = false;
    slice->slice_ratio = 100;
    dbSlice.push_back(*slice);
}
```

Then i call the init_slice() function in the main().
It's giving me errors relating to the decleration of the variable which i am not able to solve:

```
Error  C2065   'dbSlice_str' : iidentifier not declared in listVariables.h
Error  C2923   'std::vector' : 'dbSlice_str 'is not a valid model argument for the' _Ty 'parameter in listVAriables.h
Error  C3203   'allocator' : non-specialized model class cannot be used as a model argument for the model parameter '_Alloc'; expected real type   in listVariables.h
Error  C2663   'std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc>::push_back' : 2 overloads have no conversion allowed for the 'this' pointer in dbSlice.cpp
```

Could you please help me with this?

thank you.

Comment: what is `fMHK`? 
Also can you set your locale to `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` before calling the compiler so everyone can understand the output? :) French is nice but everyone can't read it unfortunately.

Comment: fMHK is the name of the project. I updated the error part i didn't pay attention that it was in french.

Comment: I have to admit the message is confusing but I think either: `dbSlice_str` isn't decalared or `dbSlice_str` is templated, which means you would have to specify `extern vector dbSlice_str<somthing>> dbSlice;` to use it in a vector because containers need to an explicit template specialization (e.g knowing all the template parameters) to be able to know the size of the object you're putting in your vector.